# Kids on a $45$-seat bus

Tags: fractions

(I'm only a Year $7$ so please explain clearly how you found the solution.)

A bus has $45$ seats. Each seat can fit two children or one child with his backpack.
If $2/3$ of the children have  backpacks, how many children can be seated on the bus?

I started by saying that $45 \times 2= 90$ if no one was wearing a backpack. But since $2/3$ of the kids are, $45/3 \times 2= 30$ children would need their own seat and $90-30= 60$. So I thought $60$ children would fit in the bus. Apparently the answer was $54$, but why?

P.S. I don't know Markdown, so somebody please edit this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting 30 from 90 means that you're removing some children from the bus -- but those you are kicking out *all have backpacks*. Therefore, *among those that are left* on the bus, those with backpacks are more than two thirds.

In other words, you now have a bus with 30 kids *without* backpacks and 30 kids *with* -- and those 60 kids do excatly fill out all the seats, but now only *half* of them have backpacks.

A better way to proceed would be to note that every group of *three* children (two with backpacks, one without) will need $2\frac12$ seats, which is $5$ half-seats. There are $90$ half-seats in the bus, so there must be $\frac{90}{5}=18$ groups of $3$ children, for a total of $18\times 3=54$ children.

Answer (score 2):

If you know basic equations, here's my explanation:

Let $N$ be the number of children we want to know.

Then we know, that 2/3 of then (i.e. 2N/3) need their own seat. The rest of them (N/3) needs only half a seat (since two children fit on one seat). So, we have

$$45=\frac{2}{3}N\cdot 1+\frac{1}{3}N\cdot \frac{1}{2} $$

If we summarize, we get

$$45=\frac{5}{6}N$$

And hence $N=\frac{6}{5}\cdot 45=54$.